# Most viable WebSocket/Perl solution

Tags: javascript, perl, apache, websocket, mod-perl

The company I'm working at uses Perl for all "backend related" stuff. However, we would like to use some real-time communication between server-processes and connected clients via browser.

We are also using Apache as Webserver with *mod.perl*. So that is my first question, I don't see any practical way to combine a WebSocket-Server in that constelation. Maybe there is one I didn't found yet?

The only thing which really works serious about that topic, is *Mojolicious*. However I'm not that experienced with that yet, so I'd be happy if someone could state if I can use that in my  current mod-perl environment. I think I also would have to let this run as *standalone webserver process*, No?

Which brings me to my second question. What is the best practice, if you have multiple perl files, which do certain things running on *Apache/modperl*, but you want to keep all your connected users informed about things. What I mean is, all these scripts are accessed via *XHR*, but some actions require other users to get informed. Currently, we do a classic *ajax polling*.

The problem I'm struggling around with is, that if there is a *dedicated websocket server*, which runs independently, all those scripts would need to somehow communicate with this process as well right ? How would one do that? Pipes? Sockets? Shared memory ?

Theoretically, if I would choose to go with such an independent *ws server* solution, I could write it in any language right? Could even be Ruby or Node. I'm just wondering if that is the best way or if there is a good solution which is more integrated in existing perl/modperl constructs.

**TL;DR**
Is it best practice to have a *standalone, independent web-socket server* which communicates with the rest of your *Apache/modperl* scripts aswell as with its connected clients ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look on AnyEvent CPAN module:
http://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent

With it you can write your own standalone event-driven WebSocket-server, also you could find a lot of examples in google or in AnyEvent's perldoc.

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP question in 2012, there is now the perl module [WebSocket](https://metacpan.org/pod/WebSocket) on CPAN, which is easy to use and versatile.

If you use Apache, you may want to use reverse proxy like:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /wss            ws://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse /wss     ws://localhost:8080
```

And have a perl script use `WebSocket::Server`